# Using LINQ to XML to query the width & height attributes for each <img> tag in XML document

Tags: linq-to-xml

I am converting HTML files into XML. How do I use LINQ to XML to query the width & height attributes for each `<img>` tag in the document? Regardless of their location in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load("doc.xml");
  foreach (var descendant in xmlDoc.Descendants("img"))
        {
           if (descendant.Attribute("width") != null)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(descendant.Attribute("width"));

          ..........
        }
```

Also [LINQ to HTML](http://www.justagile.com/linq-to-html.aspx) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

First of all LINQ to XML works on XML and an HTML document is usually not following the XML syntax rules. So unless you have a well-formed XHTML document LINQ to XML is not helping to process your HTML document.

If you have a well-formed XHTML document then do e.g.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("doc.xhtml");
XNamespace xhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
var imagedata = from img in doc.Descendants(xhtml + "img")
                select new { width = (int)img.Attribute("width"), height = (int)img.Attribute("height") };
```

That assumes however that any img element in the document has both with and height attribute. If not you would get an exception. Does that help? If you have arbitrary HTML documents not parse-able as XML you could look into HTML agility pack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ instead.